# virt-manager guests aren't able to connect to virbr0 NAT network

Tags: virtual-machine, network-interface, libvirt

I reinstalled my OS, Fedora and isntalled virtmanager again.

My old VMs can't ping 192.168.122.1 anymore. I set them to NAT originally and did not change them.
I create new VMs as well, same thing, **cant connect to network**.

Virt manager automically installed virbr0 to serve the .122 subnet to the VMs

Ran:

```
$ nmtui
```

to get:

virbr0 bridge has vnet0 slave.
Addresses 192.168.122.1/24
Gateway was empty so I filled it in 192.168.122.1 but to not effect.

Does anyone know what I can look for next?

Comment: Could you give the output of these commands while a VM is running to get a better idea on the host's network settings? `ip -br link; ip -br address; ip route`. Then if this VM is also running Linux, can you also give its own results for the previous commands?

Comment: @A.B I deleted all the adapters because internet stopped working XD So I'm going to try again with less variables and will update or delete soon